# Google Local Service API - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-nodejs-client, lsa

Since last Friday, I am getting a 500 Internal Server ERROR while using Google Local Services API; through Auth2.0 Method as per the documentation.
https://services.google.com/fh/files/helpcenter/lsa_api_dev_guide.pdf

I am sending the following request url and header:

```
request = 'https://localservices.googleapis.com/v1/accountReports:search?query=manager_customer_id:8067322687'

token ='ya29.A0AVA9y1tEQEvxw7u_6XpV3ouZpkCUFKmm66_le7X-utmDcqtu08PRQiA8aSXnzHFKioeU7K71S55slIKsGURG9X6ecuzzCHI_9Yk0APXAG2orgQozxfg2AgBbO37QYGLQHsuUmLcMlb46TNfBORN47M8aB998PiAYUNnWUtBVEFTQVRBU0ZRRTY1ZHI4RnZXLW1MdTVwQjBzN3RjMVFodHdBZw0166'

headers: 
{
    Authorization: 'Bearer  ' + token,
}
scope = [ttps://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords]
```

And getting this response:

```
response: {
    "error": {
        "code": 500,
        "message": "Internal error encountered.",
        "status": "INTERNAL"
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with this service and unable to test it. However, `500` is strongly indicative that it's the Google service that's at fault and not your code. You should contact Google support. If you can find the appropriate component then consider filing an issue on Google's [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com)

Comment: Yeah, I have already raised an issue in  Google Help Desk. https://support.google.com/google-ads#topic=10286612

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue. This morning I checked again and now API is working fine again. Google has fixed the issue!

Comment: Right!
Same here.